# TypeError: pipe_1.pipeFromArray(...) is not a function

Tags: reactjs, redux, rxjs, pouchdb

I try to fetch results from an API and store these into a front-side database with a function that return a Promise. I'm doing it in a Redux Epic with the following code:

```
export default (action$) =>
  action$.pipe(
    ofType(PATIENT_MINUTE_BLOCKS_FETCH),
    switchMap(({payload}) => {
      const {id, dateStart, dateEnd} = payload
      // this is the API call
      return fetchSessionMinuteBlocks({
        patientId: id,
        dateStart: moment(dateStart).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
        dateEnd: moment(dateEnd).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
      }).pipe(
        mergeMap(response => {
          if (!('errors' in response)) {
            let {data: {sessionMetricsMinuteBlocks}} = response
            // this is where I return either failure or success after storeSessionMinuteBlocks resolution
            return from(storeSessionMinuteBlocks(id, sessionMetricsMinuteBlocks))
              .pipe(of(patientMinuteBlocksFetchFulfilled()))
          }
          return of(patientMinuteBlocksFetchFailure(response))
        }),
        catchError(error => {
          console.error('ERROR : ', error)
          return of(patientMinuteBlocksFetchFailure(error.graphQLErrors))
        })
      )
    })
  )
```

Here is the content of the storeSessionMinuteBlocks function:

```
export default (id, data) => {
  if (data && data.list) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      db.then(db => {
        /** Bulk insert into RxDB */
        db.session_minute_blocks.pouch.bulkDocs(
          data.list.map(value => {
            /* Remove __typename from object as it's a forbidden property in pouchDB schema */
            const {
              __typename,
              ...elem
            } = value

            return {
              ...elem,
              sessionId: `${value.sessionId}`,
              patientId: id
            }
          })
        )
          .then(result => resolve(result))
          .catch(error => console.error(error))
      })
    })
  }
}
```

The catchError is triggered, and I get the following error when the API call is done:
[image: Error when doing the pipe]

If I log the results returned by when the bulkDocs function has finished, every rows are nicely inserted in database. Like this:
[image: results of bulkDocs]
and so on ...

I tried to:

- Get rid of the `new Promise`
- directly returns Promise made bulkDocs
- return (or not) the resolve value
- Verify my imports
- re-install deps and rebuild the project

I even have a very similar piece of code that works.

I don't understand why this error ? I could find only one reference to it on the internet, and it has nothing to do with my context. Is there a super hero here, who have a bloody idea what can cause this ? thanks !

Comment: You use `of` inside your pipe. This is not correct, because `of` is not a pipeable operator. Maybe you want to do `pipe(map(() => of(…)))`?

Comment: What RxJS version you have?

Comment: @martin I use the version 6.4.0 of rxjs.

Comment: @BizzyBob you are totally right, nice catch ! I have a different error that state that  `Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.`. I'll dig more into it, thanks for your eagle eye !

Comment: update: I solved issue by just doing
``return from(storeSessionMinuteBlocks(id, sessionMetricsMinuteBlocks)).pipe(map(() => patientMinuteBlocksFetchFulfilled()))``

doing map and removing of. Thanks to @BizzyBob ;)